# Rust: Receive AMQP messages from Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, rust, amqp, azure-eventhub

I would like to consume an Event hub with Rust.

I've found a some promising crates, but nothing quite satisfactory:

- [Azure SDK for Rust](https://crates.io/crates/azure_sdk_for_rust) - [uses HTTPS, not AMQP](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-rust/blob/master/sdk/service_bus/src/event_hub/mod.rs)
- [Dove](https://crates.io/crates/dove) - unusable with event hubs for [missing TLS support](https://github.com/lulf/dove/issues/7)
- [ntex-amqp](https://crates.io/crates/ntex-amqp) - zero docs, broken rustls, how does it work?
- [qpid_proton](https://crates.io/crates/qpid_proton) bindings - not ready according its own status
- [actix-amqp](https://crates.io/crates/actix-amqp) - looks like ntex
- [oasis-amqp](https://crates.io/crates/oasis-amqp) - incomplete according to its own status

I haven't found any real world application using these crates.

I have created `the-hub-namespace`, `the-hub`, `the-consumer-group` and a `the-policy` with listen permission and got `the-key`.

So far I've made the most success with ntex-amqp. I had to [hotfix the rustls connector](https://github.com/ntex-rs/ntex/pull/49) as it was failing with Invalid DNS - the host name included the port number (name:port) when only the DNS name is expected.

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "tmp"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["me"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
env_logger = "0.8"
ntex-amqp = { version="0.4", git="https://github.com/BrightOpen/ntex-amqp", branch="master" }
ntex = { version="0.3", features=["rustls"], git="https://github.com/BrightOpen/ntex", branch="master" }
rustls = "0.19"
futures = "0.3"
```

src/main.rs:

```rust
use ntex::connect::rustls::RustlsConnector;
use ntex_amqp::client::{self, SaslAuth};
use ntex_amqp::codec::types::{Descriptor, Symbol, Variant};
use rustls::ClientConfig;
use std::sync::Arc;
use futures::StreamExt;

#[ntex::main]
async fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    std::env::set_var("RUST_LOG", "ntex=trace,ntex_amqp=trace,basic=trace");
    env_logger::init();

    let mut tlsconfig = ClientConfig::new();
    let certs = tlsconfig
        .root_store
        .add_pem_file(
            // This is the Azure CA cert
            &mut "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----"
                .as_bytes(),
        )
        .unwrap();
    assert_eq!(certs, (1, 0));

    let driver = client::Connector::new()
        .connector(RustlsConnector::new(Arc::new(tlsconfig)))
        .hostname("...the-hub-namespace...servicebus.windows.net")
        .connect_sasl(
            "...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net:5671",
            SaslAuth {
                authz_id: "".into(),
                authn_id: "...the-policy...".into(),
                password: "...the-key...".into(),
            },
        )
        .await
        .unwrap();
    let sink = driver.sink();

    ntex::rt::spawn(driver.start_default());

    let mut session = sink.open_session().await.unwrap();

    let mut links = vec![];

    // I have 32 partitions
    for i in 0..32u8 {
        let link = session
            .build_receiver_link(
                format!("mylink{}", i),
                format!("...the-hub.../ConsumerGroups/...the-consumer-group.../Partitions/{}", i),
            )
            .max_message_size(65535)
.property(
                Symbol::from_slice("com.microsoft:entity-type"),
                Some("8".into()),
            )
            .property(
                Symbol::from_slice("apache.org:selector-filter:string"),
                Some(Variant::Described((
                    Descriptor::Symbol(Symbol::from_slice("apache.org:selector-filter:string")),
                    Box::new(Variant::from("amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > '@latest'")),
                ))),
            )
            .open()
            .await
            .unwrap();
        link.set_link_credit(20);
        links.push(link);
    }

    let mut links = futures::stream::select_all(links);

    use futures::StreamExt;
    while let Some(msg) = links.next().await {
        eprintln!("Message: {:#?}", msg);
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

I have no clue where to set the-hub and the-consumer-group, let alone the partition number. And how do I actually receive, or react to messages? How do I handle my offset?

Update! @JesseSquire helped figure out the appropriate resource path. A little more research finally revealed the Stream implementation on ReceiverLink - where was I looking? So now I actually get some messages. Some of the above questions out of the way.

When I run this code, I get the output:

```
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex::connect::resolve] DNS resolver: resolving host "...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net:5671"
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex::connect::resolve] DNS resolver: host "...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net:5671" resolved to [13.69.64.2:5671]
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex::connect::service] TCP connector - connecting to "...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net:5671" port:5671
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex::connect::service] TCP connector - successfully connected to connecting to "...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net:5671" - Ok(13.69.64.2:5671)
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex::connect::rustls] SSL Handshake start for: "...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net"
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex::connect::rustls] SSL Handshake success: DNSNameRef("...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net")
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex_amqp::client::connector] Negotiation client protocol id: AmqpSasl
[2021-06-22T18:21:49Z TRACE ntex_amqp::client::connector] Negotiation client protocol id: Amqp
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::client::connector] Open client amqp connection: Open { container_id: "42b4f39ce51f46bf85cf8631f64d8cca", hostname: Some("...the-hub-namespace....servicebus.windows.net"), max_frame_size: 65535, channel_max: 1024, idle_time_out: Some(120000), outgoing_locales: None, incoming_locales: None, offered_capabilities: None, desired_capabilities: None, properties: None }
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::client::connector] Open confirmed: Open { container_id: "f11d7639f6454b819bbf7b1e1150c101_G6", hostname: None, max_frame_size: 65535, channel_max: 1024, idle_time_out: Some(120000), outgoing_locales: None, incoming_locales: None, offered_capabilities: None, desired_capabilities: None, properties: None }
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::connection] Session opened: local 0 remote 0
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink0" 0 -> 0
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink1" 1 -> 1
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink2" 2 -> 2
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink3" 3 -> 3
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink4" 4 -> 4
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink5" 5 -> 5
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink6" 6 -> 6
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink7" 7 -> 7
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink8" 8 -> 8
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink9" 9 -> 9
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink10" 10 -> 10
[2021-06-22T18:21:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink11" 11 -> 11
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink12" 12 -> 12
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink13" 13 -> 13
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink14" 14 -> 14
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink15" 15 -> 15
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink16" 16 -> 16
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink17" 17 -> 17
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink18" 18 -> 18
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink19" 19 -> 19
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink20" 20 -> 20
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink21" 21 -> 21
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink22" 22 -> 22
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink23" 23 -> 23
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink24" 24 -> 24
[2021-06-22T18:21:51Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink25" 25 -> 25
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink26" 26 -> 26
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink27" 27 -> 27
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink28" 28 -> 28
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink29" 29 -> 29
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink30" 30 -> 30
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Receiver link opened: "mylink31" 31 -> 31
[2021-06-22T18:21:52Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
Message: Ok(
    Transfer {
        handle: 0,
        delivery_id: Some(
            0,
        ),
        delivery_tag: Some(
            b"",
        ),
        message_format: Some(
            0,
        ),
        settled: Some(
            true,
        ),
        more: false,
        rcv_settle_mode: None,
        state: None,
        resume: false,
        aborted: false,
        batchable: true,
        body: Some(
            Data(
                b"\0Sr\xc1I\x06\xa3\x15x-opt-sequence-numberU\0\xa3\x0cx-opt-offset\xa1\x010\xa3\x13x-opt-enqueued-time\x83\0\0\x01z4\xcd\xfc \0Su\xa0\x14s6df54s65df4s6d5f4sf",
            ),
        ),
    },
)
...
[2021-06-22T18:23:37Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:24:09Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
Message: Ok(
    Transfer {
        handle: 13,
        delivery_id: Some(
            27,
        ),
        delivery_tag: Some(
            b"",
        ),
        message_format: Some(
            0,
        ),
        settled: Some(
            true,
        ),
        more: false,
        rcv_settle_mode: None,
        state: None,
        resume: false,
        aborted: false,
        batchable: true,
        body: Some(
            Data(
                b"\0Sr\xc1J\x06\xa3\x15x-opt-sequence-numberU\x01\xa3\x0cx-opt-offset\xa1\x0256\xa3\x13x-opt-enqueued-time\x83\0\0\x01z4\xf7\"\xfb\0Su\xa0\x15999999999999999999999",
            ),
        ),
    },
)
[2021-06-22T18:24:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Session received credit None. window: 4294967295, pending: 0
[2021-06-22T18:24:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:26:35Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
[2021-06-22T18:27:50Z TRACE ntex_amqp::session] Session received credit None. window: 4294967295, pending: 0
[2021-06-22T18:27:50Z TRACE ntex::framed::dispatcher] not enough data to decode next frame, register dispatch task
```

Ok, the main objective fulfilled: I can receive Event Hub messages in Rust with AMQP. It leaves a lot to desire though:

1. Filtering doesn't seem to have any effect, how do I manage offset?
2. More reliable, well maintained, battle tested crate?
3. Docs, examples?
4. At least once delivery (currently looks like at most once)

Comment: I can't help with the Rust portions, but the link path that you'll need to read messages is in the form of `[ namespace endpoint ]\[ event hub ]\ConsumerGroups\[ consumer group ]\Partitions\[ partition ]`.  You'll also need to add a link property `com.microsoft:entity-type` with the value `8` (consumer group).  The starting position needs to be set as a filter named `apache.org:selector-filter:string` with the value in the form `amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset >= [ offset value ]`  _(you can remove the equals if you want the filter to be non-inclusive of the offset)_.

Comment: If it helps, the C# source from the official Azure SDK for establishing a consumer link can be found [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Amqp/AmqpConnectionScope.cs#L600), though there are a couple of layers of abstraction for the raw values that you'll need to navigate through.   Most can be found in the [amqp](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/eventhub/Azure.Messaging.EventHubs/src/Amqp/) folder.

Comment: @JesseSquire, I've added the properties (not sure it works) and fixed the link path as suggested.  I do not see the line that receiver link has been closed remotely, so we may be onto something! Will need to test with some messages. Still not clear how to actually get them :) but thanks a lot!

Comment: @JesseSquire, I'm receiving messages now. The filtering has no effect, though. I'm sending this across: ` Symbol(
                            B:"apache.org:selector-filter:string",
                        ): Described(
                            (
                                Ulong(
                                    83483426826,
                                ),
                                String(
                                    B:"amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > '@latest'",
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),`

Comment: Glad to hear that you're at least able to get messages.  The filter key symbol looks correct to me.  The filter value looks like it may be off, though it may just be a language detail.   The `Described` type doesn't seem to reference the symbol that it is describing, just the type code.   I'm also seeing single quotes around `@latest` which I don't believe are needed.  In C# this filter value would look like:  `new AmqpDescribed("apache.org:selector-filter:string", (ulong)0x00000137000000A) { Value = "amqp.annotation.x-opt-offset > @latest" };`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a little late for you. For future viewers on this question, I have made an AMQP 1.0 implementation in rust with serde and tokio, and I have already added an example with event hubs, including one example that uses filter.

[fe2o3-amqp event_hubs example](https://github.com/minghuaw/fe2o3-amqp/tree/main/examples/event_hubs)

Comment: Impressive :) thanks!Indeed I've moved on, but will keep this one in mind! In the absence of other options I'm going to accept, though I haven't tried it yet.